# Add TextView to ListView Item

Tags: java, android, listview

I need to add ListView items that can contain different count of TextView and Imageview objects. How can I do it? And how to determine and setup the id's of this objects? When I try to add an ImageView or TextView to LinearLayout with id R.id.chat_message, the application crashes :(

```
package com.me.my_app;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FriendSendMessageActivity extends ListActivity {

    ListView view;
    public ContactAdapter contactAdapter;

    LinearLayout LL;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_send_message);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null)
        {
            int index = Integer.parseInt(extras.get(getPackageName() + ".IndexInList").toString());
            String sentFrom = extras.get(getPackageName() + ".SentFrom").toString();
            int id = Integer.parseInt(extras.get(getPackageName() + ".Id").toString()); //либо id друга либо id друга
            FriendItem.Friend item = TabFriendsActivity.getList().get(index);

            view = getListView();

            contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter();
            contactAdapter.addItem(new MessageItem.Message(1, true, true, true, "123","13:31",new ArrayList<MessageItem.Message.Attachment>()));

            ArrayList<MessageItem.Message.Attachment> list = new ArrayList<MessageItem.Message.Attachment>();
            list.add(new MessageItem.Message.Attachment(MessageAttachmentType.PHOTO, RoundedImage.createRoundedPhoto(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MainActivity.res,R.drawable.temp_user_photo))));

            contactAdapter.addItem(new MessageItem.Message(1, true, true, true, "123","9:10",list));
            view.setAdapter(contactAdapter);  
        }
    }





    class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private ArrayList<MessageItem.Message> mData = new ArrayList<MessageItem.Message>();
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

         private static final int IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = -1;
         private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;    //обычный item
         private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = 2;   //макс. число layout'ов отображения item'ов


        public ContactAdapter()
        {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }


        public void addItem(final MessageItem.Message item) {
            mData.add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        public int getItemViewType(int position) 
        {
            return TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
            return mData.size();
        }


        public MessageItem.Message getItem(int position)
        {
            return mData.get(position);
        }


        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public boolean isEnabled(int pos)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            MessageItem.ViewHolder holder = null;

            MessageItem.Message item = mData.get(position);

            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                holder = new MessageItem.ViewHolder();

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(item.in_out ? R.layout.chat_message_in_item : R.layout.chat_message_out_item,   null, false);

                if(item.listAttach.size() > 0)
                    holder.attachLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chat_message);




                for(MessageItem.Message.Attachment attach : item.listAttach)
                {   
                    switch(attach.type)
                    {
                    case PHOTO:
                        if(attach.photo != null)
                        {
                            ImageView iv = new ImageView(convertView.getContext());
                            //iv.setLayoutParams(params);
                            iv.setId(0x7f000000 - 1);
                            holder.listAttach.add(new MessageItem.Message.Attachment(attach.type,iv));
                            Log.v("","1" + iv.getId() + " " + holder.listAttach.size());
                        }
                        else
                            Log.v("", "Null!");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (MessageItem.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }



            for(int i = 0; i < holder.listAttach.size();i++)
            {
                if(holder.listAttach.get(i).type == MessageAttachmentType.PHOTO && item.listAttach.get(i).photo != null && holder.listAttach.get(i).image != null)
                {
                    holder.attachLL.addView(holder.listAttach.get(i).image);
                    holder.listAttach.get(i).image.setImageBitmap(item.listAttach.get(i).photo);
                }

                else
                    Log.v("", "Unable to add image!");
            }


            return convertView;
        }
    }





}
```

And MessageItem.java:

```
package com.me.my_app;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MessageItem
{
    public static class Message implements Comparator<Message> 
    {
        int id; 
        boolean in_out; 
        boolean is_read; 
        boolean is_delivered; 
        String message; 
        String time; 
        ArrayList<Attachment> listAttach; 
        public Message(int id, boolean in_out, boolean is_read, boolean is_delivered, String message, String time, ArrayList<Attachment> list)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.in_out = in_out;
            this.is_read = is_read;
            this.is_delivered = is_delivered;
            this.message = message;
            this.time = time;
            listAttach = new ArrayList<Attachment>();
            if(list != null)
            {
                for(Attachment a : list)
                    listAttach.add(a);
            }
        }


        public int compare(Message object1, Message object2) {
            return object1.time.compareTo(object2.time);
        }
        public static class Attachment
        {
            ImageView image; 
            MessageAttachmentType type;
            Bitmap photo; 
            String Uri; 
            public Attachment(MessageAttachmentType type, Bitmap photo) 
            {
                this.type = type;
                this.photo = photo;
            }
            public Attachment(MessageAttachmentType type, ImageView image)
            {
                this.type = type;
                this.image = image;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {   
        LinearLayout attachLL;
        TextView text, time;
        ArrayList<MessageItem.Message.Attachment> listAttach;
        public ViewHolder()
        {
            listAttach = new ArrayList<MessageItem.Message.Attachment>();
        }
    }
}
enter code here
```

Comment: Always post the logcat description of the error? Please don't expect others to go through lengthy codes to find the error when logcat usually localize/pinpoint the error zone.

Comment: The error is that holder.attachLL of type LinearLayout is null after this line:

Answer (score 1):

You will most probably have to implement your own list view adapter. Then you can create any layout for your item and set it up. Here is how it's done in my code:

```
public class ExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    /*SOME CODE HERE*/

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
        }

        int groupId = ((ListTaskElement)this.getGroup(groupPosition)).id;       
        this.setupTaskView(convertView, this.childrenOfGroup(groupId, false).get(childPosition));

        convertView.setTag(this.getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition));
        return convertView;
    }

    /*SOME CODE HERE*/

}
```

You can find all the details here: http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/12/19/custom-android-listadapter.aspx

Comment: Is it important to use BaseExpandableListAdapter? I don't have an ExpandableList, only ListView. Can you provide a working example?

Comment: @igla, check out this page: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_adapterintro for working examples. Name of class changes, but the idea doesn't.